# How to capture response status of all the Get/post request from page using Webdriver

Tags: java, rest, http, selenium, webdriver

When hit any url in browser. Multiple get/post/delete method is submitted. I want to capture a status of these methods.

Tried with  below program but it gives a webpage status

```
   String url = "http://www.google.com/";
     WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
     HtmlPage htmlPage = webClient.getPage(url);
     try{
     //verify response
     Assert.assertEquals(200,htmlPage.getWebResponse().getStatusCode());
     System.out.println(true);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

We have a utility class using [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to get GET response codes, but you could use that same approach to get other methods using the setRequestMethod method.  Here's how we get the GET responses:

```
private static int getResponseCode(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    con.setConnectTimeout(connection_time_out);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    if(con != null){
        con.disconnect();
    }
    return responseCode;
}
```